# Deep save associated models with relation back to first model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have 3 models: A, B, C.

A hasMany B

A hasMany C

B hasMany C

```
    A
   / \
  /   \
 /     \
|       |
^       ^
B ----< C
```

I created the view and the controller add method.

The forms data:

```
$data = array(
    'A' => array(
        'id' => '',
        'name' => 'alpha',
        'B' => array(
            'id' => '',
            'name' => 'beta',
            'C' => array(
                'id' => '',
                'name' => 'gamma'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I save the forms data with the `$this->A->saveAssociated($data, ['deep' => true])` call.

If I query the newly created A model, I get the following data:

```
array(
    'A' => array(
        'id' => (int) 111,
        'name' => 'alpha',
        'B' => array(
            'id' => (int) 9,
            'a_id' => (int) 111,
            'name' => 'beta',
            'C' => array(
                'id' => (int) 78,
                'b_id' => (int) 9,
                'a_id' => (int) 0,
                'name' => 'gamma'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

My problem is that C models `a_id` field doesnt has good value / isnt related to the newly created A model.

Is it possible to save them with one `saveAssociated($data, ['deep' => true])` call?

Comment: You need to show an example of the `$data` you are saving.

Comment: If I can save and query the data. Is it REALLY needed?
But here you go. :)

Comment: I think I need a way to override Cake foreign key setter method during save.

Comment: Thanks. Showing the data being saved has helped clarify what your asking. I've added an answer/suggestion (not sure if it helps).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit of a quirky situation and one that CakePHP won't be able to handle without some help. When CakePHP saves the foreign keys it is in relation to its immediate relation. So in your case when Cake saves model `C` it only knows to set the `C.b_id` foreign key. Your `C` data would need to be a child array of `A` for it to set `C.a_id`, but then it wouldn't set `C.b_id`.

There is possibly a better way of handling this, but one solution would be to add the `C.a_id` foreign key after saving:-

```
if ($this->A->saveAssociated($data, ['deep' => true]) !== false) {
    // Set the a_id foreign key for the newly created C record.
    $cData = [
        'id' => $this->A->B->C->id,
        'a_id' => $this->A->id
    ];
    $this->A->C->save($cData, true, ['id', 'a_id']);
}
```

Comment: Yes I did similar, it works.
I want to find a more MVC and DRY way to do it.

Comment: I think the problem is how you have your data structure. Why is `C` associated with `A` when it can be reached via `B`?

Comment: Because sometimes it cant.

My product (A) has components of (B), which optionally a component of (C).

There are products which only hasMany (B).

Comment: If you want a dry approach you could always take my example code and refactor that into a save method in a behavior that can be reused.